# Using PHPUnit and ZF2 Factory

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpunit

I would like to implement PHPUnit tests for my factory, which calls a service.
Here is my factory :

```
class FMaiAffaireServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $dbAdapter = $serviceLocator->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');

        $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
        $tableGateway = new TableGateway(
            'f_affaire',
            $dbAdapter,
            null,
            $resultSetPrototype
        );
        $adapter = $tableGateway->getAdapter();
        $sql = new Sql($adapter);

        $maiAffaireTable = new FMaiAffaireTable(
            $tableGateway,
            $adapter,
            $sql
        );

        $typeaffaireService = $serviceLocator->get(
            'Intranet\Service\Model\PTypeaffaireService'
        );

        $etatAffaireService = $serviceLocator->get(
            'Intranet\Service\Model\PEtataffaireService'
        );

        $maiPrestationService = $serviceLocator->get(
            'Maintenance\Service\Model\PMaiPrestationService'
        );

        $maiAffaireService = new FMaiAffaireService(
            $maiAffaireTable,
            $typeaffaireService,
            $etatAffaireService,
            $maiPrestationService
        );

        return $maiAffaireService;
    }
```

Ad there is my test but it doesn't work :

```
class FMaiAffaireServiceFactoryTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testCreateService()
    {
        $sm = new ServiceManager();
        $factory = new FMaiAffaireServiceFactory();
        $runner = $factory->createService($sm);
    }
}
```

**Edit : My New test script :**

```
public function testCreateService()
    {
        $this->mockDriver = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\DriverInterface');
        $this->mockConnection = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\ConnectionInterface');
        $this->mockDriver->expects($this->any())->method('checkEnvironment')->will($this->returnValue(true));
        $this->mockDriver->expects($this->any())->method('getConnection')->will($this->returnValue($this->mockConnection));
        $this->mockPlatform = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\PlatformInterface');
        $this->mockStatement = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\StatementInterface');
        $this->mockDriver->expects($this->any())->method('createStatement')->will($this->returnValue($this->mockStatement));
        $this->adapter = new Adapter($this->mockDriver, $this->mockPlatform);
        $this->sql = new Sql($this->adapter);


        $mockTableGateway = $this->getMock('Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway', array(), array(), '', false);


        $smMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager')
                       ->getMock();

        $maiPrestationTable = $this->getMockBuilder('Maintenance\Model\BDD\PMaiPrestationTable')
             ->setMethods(array())
             ->setConstructorArgs(array($mockTableGateway, $this->adapter, $this->sql))
             ->getMock();

        $smMock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('get')
            ->with('Maintenance\Service\Model\PMaiPrestationService')
            ->will($this->returnValue(new PMaiPrestationService($maiPrestationTable)));

        $etatAffaireTable = $this->getMockBuilder('Intranet\Model\BDD\PEtataffaireTable')
            ->setMethods(array())
            ->setConstructorArgs(array($mockTableGateway))
            ->getMock();

        $smMock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('get')
            ->with('Intranet\Service\Model\PEtataffaireService')
            ->will($this->returnValue(new PEtataffaireService($etatAffaireTable)));

        $typeaffaireTable = $this->getMockBuilder('Intranet\Model\BDD\PTypeaffaireTable')
            ->setMethods(array())
            ->setConstructorArgs(array($mockTableGateway))
            ->getMock();

        $smMock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('get')
            ->with('Intranet\Service\Model\PTypeaffaireService')
            ->will($this->returnValue(new PTypeaffaireService($typeaffaireTable)));

        $smMock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('get')
            ->with('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')
            ->will($this->returnValue($this->adapter));

        $factory = new FMaiAffaireServiceFactory();
        $runner = $factory->createService($smMock);
        // assertions here
    }
```

This tells me : get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter

**Edit : Here is the service :**

```
public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
        {
            $dbAdapter = $serviceLocator->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');

            $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
            $tableGateway = new TableGateway(
                'f_affaire',
                $dbAdapter,
                null,
                $resultSetPrototype
            );
            $adapter = $tableGateway->getAdapter();
            $sql = new Sql($adapter);

            $maiAffaireTable = new FMaiAffaireTable(
                $tableGateway,
                $adapter,
                $sql
            );

            $typeaffaireService = $serviceLocator->get(
                'Intranet\Service\Model\PTypeaffaireService'
            );

            $etatAffaireService = $serviceLocator->get(
                'Intranet\Service\Model\PEtataffaireService'
            );

            $maiPrestationService = $serviceLocator->get(
                'Maintenance\Service\Model\PMaiPrestationService'
            );

            $maiAffaireService = new FMaiAffaireService(
                $maiAffaireTable,
                $typeaffaireService,
                $etatAffaireService,
                $maiPrestationService
            );

            return $maiAffaireService;
        }
```

How can I make it work ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test a factory, you don't need to use the actual service manager. If you did, you'd test the ServiceManager class as well, breaking the rule to test one thing at a time only.

Instead, you can test the factories methods directly and mock the service manager:

```
class FMaiAffaireServiceFactoryTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function testCreateService()
    {
        /** @var ServiceManager|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject $smMock */
        $smMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager')
            ->getMock();
        $smMock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('get')
            ->with('Intranet\Service\Model\PTypeaffaireService')
            ->will($this->returnValue(new PTypeaffaireService()));
        // more mocked returns here

        $factory = new FMaiAffaireServiceFactory();
        $runner = $factory->createService($smMock);
        // assertions here
    }

}
```

In case of a service manager, you need to define the return yourself, instead of using the other factories (which would mean to test all those factories, too).

Note that the returned objects might need to be mocked as well. For example your database adapter.

You find more about mock objects in PHPUnit here:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/all-about-mocking-with-phpunit--net-27252

**Edit:** Here are two possible solutions for mocking a service manager in your case:

First of all, you need to mock all dependencies. Once again, *this is an example!* I don't know how your other classes look like, so you might need to disable the constructor, define methods etc.

```
/** @var Adapter|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject $smMock */
$adapterMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();
$typeaffaireService = $this->getMock('Intranet\Service\Model\PEtataffaireService');
$etataffaireService = $this->getMock('Intranet\Service\Model\PTypeaffaireService');
$maiPrestationService = $this->getMock('Maintenance\Service\Model\PMaiPrestationService');
```

**First solution:** By callback, pretty flexible solution for not testing dependencies.

This mock doesn't care if a dependency is not injected by getting the instance via the service manager etc. It just makes sure the service manager mock is able to return a mock of the required class.

```
$smReturns = array(
    'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => $adapterMock,
    'Intranet\Service\Model\PTypeaffaireService' => $etataffaireService,
    'Intranet\Service\Model\PEtataffaireService' => $typeaffaireService,
    'Maintenance\Service\Model\PMaiPrestationService' => $maiPrestationService,
);

/** @var ServiceManager|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject $smMock */
$smMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager')
    ->getMock();
$smMock->expects($this->any())
    ->method('get')
    ->will($this->returnCallback(function($class) use ($smReturns) {
        if(isset($smReturns[$class])) {
            return $smReturns[$class];
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }));
```

**Second Solution:** By specifying single method calls.

This is the strict solution, it will throw an error if one of the dependencies is not injected or even if the instance was requested at the wrong time.

```
/** @var ServiceManager|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject $smMock */
$smMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager')
    ->getMock();
$smMock->expects($this->at(0))
    ->method('get')
    ->with('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')
    ->will($this->returnValue($adapterMock));
$smMock->expects($this->at(1))
    ->method('get')
    ->with('Intranet\Service\Model\PTypeaffaireService')
    ->will($this->returnValue($typeaffaireService));
$smMock->expects($this->at(2))
    ->method('get')
    ->with('Intranet\Service\Model\PEtataffaireService')
    ->will($this->returnValue($etataffaireService));
$smMock->expects($this->at(3))
    ->method('get')
    ->with('Maintenance\Service\Model\PMaiPrestationService')
    ->will($this->returnValue($maiPrestationService));
```

Comment: Hummmm thanks but it tells ... "Parameter 0 for invocation Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get('Zend\Db\Adap
ter\Adapter', true) does not match expected value.
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'Maintenance\Model\BDD\FMaiAffaireTable'
+'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'"

Comment: Of course it does, this was just an example of how you might want to implement a mock of the service manager, not the final solution.
I will edit my answer and add a more general solution for the mock object, but I still recommend to read the tutorial about mock objects. You will need them quite frequently when working with PHPUnit

Comment: I don't understad the order to place my mocks ! my error changes everytime ! i'm completely lost ! i put on edit my new code ...

Comment: Don't worry, mocking objects might seem to behave strange at first, but you will learn to like them with the time. Especially because mocking is a lot of work, but makes your tests independent and in case something goes wrong - you will know exactly where to look for the bug.

Answer (score 0):

A factory that creates one real object requiring four other dependency objects should only ever use four mock objects for this.

Now look at your factory code and see the difference between the first part and the second part: Creating the last three arguments for the `FMaiAffaireService` object is nice and clean: Grab three objects from the service manager, and you are done. This is easily mocked, even though a bit repetitive.

But that first argument obviously requires five mock objects, two real objects, mocking at least three methods inside these objects (not counting the number of methods being called in the real objects). Additionally, the last three arguments all get instantiated as real objects with mocked arguments for themselves.

What can you test with a factory? The only real assertion you can do in a test is whether the factory holds true to it's contract and deliver an object of a certain type. You have unit tests for that object somewhere else, so it isn't too useful to grab an object full of mocks from the factory and then do some real work with it!

Stick to the simplest possible test to make your factory code be able to pass. There are no loops, no conditions, so it is really easy to get 100% code coverage in one single test.

Your factory should look like this:

```
public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
{
    $maiAffaireTable = $serviceLocator->get('WHATEVER\CLASS\KEY\YOU\THINK');
    $typeaffaireService = $serviceLocator->get('Intranet\Service\Model\PTypeaffaireService');
    $etatAffaireService = $serviceLocator->get('Intranet\Service\Model\PEtataffaireService');
    $maiPrestationService = $serviceLocator->get('Maintenance\Service\Model\PMaiPrestationService');

    $maiAffaireService = new FMaiAffaireService(
        $maiAffaireTable,
        $typeaffaireService,
        $etatAffaireService,
        $maiPrestationService
    );

    return $maiAffaireService;
}
```

The idea is that an object with four objects as dependencies is a complicated beast, and the factory should be trying to be as clean and easy to understand as possible. For that reason, building that maiAffaireTable object is pushed into a different factory, which will lead to an easier test for only that single aspect in that respective factory - not in THIS test.

You only require five mocks: Four of them are mocking the arguments for your `FMaiAffaireService` object, the fifth is the service manager:

```
    $smMock = $this->getMockBuilder(\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $FMaiAffaireTableMock = $this->getMockBuilder(FMaiAffaireTable::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();


    $PTypeaffaireServiceMock = $this->getMockBuilder(PTypeaffaireService::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $PEtataffaireServiceMock = $this->getMockBuilder(PEtataffaireService::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $PMaiPrestationServiceMock = $this->getMockBuilder(PMaiPrestationService::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
```

Note that I switched from using strings containing the class names to mock to using the `::class` static constant that contains the fully qualified class name, even when you are using `use` to import classes into your namespace. This works since PHP 5.5 (and using it is so much better compared to using strings: Autocompletion of your IDE, support when refactoring...).

Now the necessary setup: The only mocked object that will have methods called is the service manager, and it should emit the other mocks in arbitrary order without complaining. That's what the [`returnValueMap()`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest5.php) is for:

```
$mockMap = [
    ['WHATEVER\CLASS\KEY\YOU\THINK', $FMaiAffaireTableMock],
    ['Intranet\Service\Model\PTypeaffaireService', $PTypeaffaireServiceMock],
    ['Intranet\Service\Model\PEtataffaireService',  $PEtataffaireServiceMock],
    ['Maintenance\Service\Model\PMaiPrestationService',  $PMaiPrestationServiceMock]
];
$smMock->expects($this->any())->method('get')->will($this->returnValueMap($mockMap));
```

Now for the final test:

```
$factory = new FMaiAffaireServiceFactory();
$result = $factory->createService($smMock);
$this->assertInstanceOf(FMaiAffaireService::class, $result);
```

And this is it: Instantiate the service manager and all mocks it should emit, put them into a map array, and run the factory method once to see if the object is getting created.

If this simple test does not work with your code, you are doing something wrong in your code. The only real code that gets executed here besided the factory itself is the constructor of the created object. This constructor should not do anything besides copying the passed arguments into internal members. Don't access the database, filesystem, network, anything. If you want to do that: Call a method after the object is instantiated.

Note that I do not care about the service manager being called at all. The factory method requires me to pass this object, but whether it is called ten times, zero times, for all configured objects in alphabetical order, or randomly: This does not matter at all, it is an implementation detail of this factory method. Changing the order of the calls should not break the test. The only relevant thing is that the code works and returns the correct object. Having to configure the service manager is the required amount of work that has to be done to make the code run.